# Insert statement not inserting value for one field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I'm working on some SQL for a program I am developing, and I am having an odd issue that I've never really seen before.  Here is the query that's giving me trouble:

```
insert into [db].[dbo].[table] (JobNum, JobSeq, OperationNumber, WorkCenter,
 ResourceGroup, Material, MaterialQuantity, MaterialCost, LbrHoursPerPiece, 
 ExtendedDescription, PreviousMaterial, UniqueID) 
values ('J000001234', 1234, 123, 'UFAN', 'FANASSY', '12345678', 
 4, 50, 1, 'DESC', '', '')
```

I then do a select from the same table:

```
SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
where JobNum = 'J000001234'
```

And this is what is returned:

[image: query results]

For some reason, even though I give it a value of 50, the MaterialCost field is showing NULL, and I can't figure out why when everything else is being inserted properly.  Here is the table design, just in case:

[image: Table Design]

Any thoughts?

EDIT:  I want to point out that while this is a query I'm using in .NET code, for now I am only testing it in SQL Server Management Studio.

Also, a commenter asked for the create query, so:

```
...
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table](
[JobNum] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[JobSeq] [int] NOT NULL,
[OperationNumber] [int] NULL,
[WorkCenter] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
[ResourceGroup] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[Material] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[MaterialQuantity] [decimal](18, 8) NULL,
[MaterialCost] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
[LbrHoursPerPiece] [decimal](10, 5) NULL,
[ExtendedDescription] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
[PreviousMaterial] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
[UniqueID] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] ADD  CONSTRAINT     [DF_Table_MaterialCost]  DEFAULT ((0.00)) FOR [MaterialCost]
GO
```

EDIT 2:  So I took the CREATE TABLE query and used it to create another table, tableTEST, that is identical to the trouble table.  When executing the same query on the TEST table, it worked fine.  I also want to point out that the MaterialCost field that isn't getting the right data was added to the table much later after initially creating it.

Comment: Have you tried a null input any other column? Does it raise any error?

Comment: Brian:  Either 50, 50.00 or '50.00', none of them seem to work.

Comment: Are you inserting it to the intended database? I mean the intended instance? Just saying.

Comment: I presume there isn't a trigger behind the table?

Comment: can't see why the default would cause any issues, but as it's the only constraint, try removing it

Comment: No triggers.  Rajiv, for now I am simply testing the query in Management studio and then immediately running a SELECT statement on the same table, where I am getting either NULL or the default column value, not the value that is in the INSERT statement.

Comment: try doing the insert in ssms and see if it croaks on the statement.

Comment: does a specific update after insertion change the value?

`UPDATE [db].[dbo].[table] SET MaterialCost=50 WHERE JobNum='J000001234'`

Comment: I agree with Brian. Try running the insert statement on SSMS.

Comment: Hans:  The update statement does work, so it's just the insert statement that isn't setting the column value properly.  Brian and Rajiv, for now I am doing all of this in SSMS.

Comment: try dropping the column along with the default value and then adding it back.  maybe there is some weirdness that happened when adding the column previously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I was able to solve the problem without ever discovering the root cause.  The MaterialCost field was added to the table much later after it already had a fairly large amount of data, so there was obviously something odd going on there.

To fix my problem, I created a copy of the original table, copied all of the data over to the new table, and dropped the original.  After doing that, the insert statement worked properly.  So like I said, it works now, but I don't really have any details on the root cause, other than that field being new.

Comment: Just ran into this problem on SQL Server 2016 10 years later and Microsoft has still not addressed this...

Answer (score 0):

Remove allow nulls on that column and see if the program raises an exception. I am sure it would. some where your code is not putting a value into that column.

Comment: I had tried that.  If I remove allow nulls, it will just insert whatever the default value is, in my case '0.00'.

Also, as I added in an edit to my original post, I am currently just testing the query in SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is '0.00000'.  Also, added the CREATE TABLE query to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Check for a triggers, something could be removing your value if it doesn't fit a business rule.